# Actualización de base de datos

Tags: android, base-de-datos

Mediante un programa externo creo la base de datos y genero un fichero con extensión .db que lo alojo en la carpeta `assets`.

Mediante una clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper` recojo los datos para general la base de datos.

Una vez que la app este en Google Play, si realizo un cambio en el fichero con extensión .db cuando el usuario realice la actualización se le actualizará la base de datos, simplemente cambiando el valor de `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;`a `2`?

Esta es mi clase (he omitido algunas variables para que sea mas limpio el código):

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //Variables ausiliares
    private static String DB_PATH="data/data/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo/databases/";
    private static final String DB_NAME="kmlezoibilbideak.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        //para chequear que existe la BD
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        SQLiteDatabase db_read = null;

        if(dbExist){
            //Do nothing

        }else{
            //agarramos la BD para leerla y despues la cerramos.
            db_read = this.getReadableDatabase();
            db_read.close();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
                Log.i("LogApp", "DatabaseHelper. createDataBase. BD cargada.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                throw new Error("Error copying database (DatabaseHelper. createDataBase)");
            }//db_read.close();
        }

    }

    //Checkeamos si actualmente la BD existe o no en la app
    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();

    }

    //vamos a volcar
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db. Destination folder (where we created the DB empty)
        String outFileName = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream. //We opened it BBDD empty as OutputStream
        OutputStream myOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        //Para trasnferir el fichero en tamaños de 1024 bytes
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int lenght;

        //while para que nos mande el archivo.
        //while ((lenght = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        while((lenght = myInput.read(buffer))!=-1){
            if(lenght > 0){

                myOutPut.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
                //con esto hemos copiado la base de datos. Basicamente, El volcado del archivo
                //Log.i("DataBaseHelper", "copyDataBase: ESTOY EN copyDataBase WHILE");
            }

        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutPut.flush();
        myOutPut.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    //Para abrir la base de datos
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //Log.e("Checking", "RutasEnListaActivity. openDataBase");

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    //Para cerrar la base de datos
    public synchronized void close(){

        if(myDatabase != null){
            myDatabase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    //Los METODOS para interactuar con los datos de la BD


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: buenas, con que programa creas los .db?

Comment: Uso Valentina studio.

Comment: @Webserveis Nunca había escuchado Valentina Studio, regularmente se usa http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: @Elenasys conoces el SqlScout tiene muy buena pinta, por los videos que he visto http://www.idescout.com/ (no es free) se integra dentro de android studio

Comment: @Elenasys esta es la web del programa http://valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview

Comment: @aldakur muchas gracias por la información, tiene mucho más features y todo un kit! voy a probar la versión libre, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Cambiando el valor de `DATABASE_VERSION` y llamando con este a `super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);` lo que consegirás es que invoque al método `onUpgrade`. Yo he solido borrar la BBDD anterior para copiar la nueva que está en la carpeta `assets`

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) // esto no sería necesario, puesto que si se llama a ésta función se supone que se cumple la condición
    { 
        try
        {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT valor_a_mantener", null);
            variable_a_mantener = -1; 
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
                variable_a_mantener = cursor.getInt(0);
            cursor.close();

            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH+DATABASE_NAME);
            dbFile.delete();
            copyDataBase();

            // hacer INSERT de valor_a_mantener
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { 
            throw new Error("Error upgrading database: " + e.getMessage()); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: No entra en el método `onUpgrade` . Cambio el valor  de `DATABASE_VERSION` e instancio `DatabaseHelper` de esta manera      `DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);` en el `MainActivity.java`

Answer (score 1):

Regularmente la versión de la base de datos  `DATABASE_VERSION` se obtiene a partir del `versionCode` definido en la aplicación, cuando el `versionCode` cambia, como en el caso de una actualización se debe activar el método `onUpgrade()`

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
..
..
}
```

En tu caso es correcto lo que comentas, cambia el valor de la variable `DATABASE_VERSION` a un valor mayor y al ocurrir esto se debe llamar el método `onUpgrade()`, pero el llamado debes definirlo por ejemplo en el splashscreen, y  dentro debes implementar que es lo que requieres.

Generalmente se realiza si es que lo requieres un drop de la tabla y la creación de una nueva estructura, llamando el método `onCreate()`.

```
  @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

          if(oldVersion < newVersion)  {
              db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MiTabla.TABLE_NAME);
              MiTabla.onCreate(db);
          }

    }
```

Comentas que lees una base de datos de assets, no me gusta recomendar librerías pero esta es una excepción, te recomiendo ampliamente el uso de [**SQLiteAssetHelper**](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), que tiene implementado todo lo que necesitas al leer una BD en `/assets`.

Comment: Cambio el valor de `DATABASE_VERSION`pero no entra en el `onUpgrade`

Comment: Si por ejemplo hago la siguiente llamada `SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();`entonces sí entra en el metódo onUpgrade